# Safe to assume majority of mobile visitors will have double density display?

Tags: mobile

Im designing a mobile website. Some of my styling is not absolutely necessary for understanding the content but does help.

It looks fine on a double density display but not on a normal display. So when I test with my iPhone it looks great but when I re-size the browser on my PC down to 320px it doenst look right. As the iPhone's display pretends to be 320 but is actually 640, this is why it looks fine.

Is it safe to assume that the vast majority of mobile visitors will have a double density display?

Comment: Short answer - no. It's never safe to assume anything unless you have actual stats and figures of your target audience.

Comment: @JonW That's the correct answer, you should probably write it up as a long answer.

Comment: It depends entirely on who the vast majority of visitors to your site is. But, in general, why would you want to design something that only works on retina anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - because the device pixel ratio might be [1.0, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0](http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/) - or something else.

Mine's 1.5 for example.

So you're designing a mobile website - are people *only* going to look at it on a mobile device?

Don't make the mistake of *designing for the mobile web* - **there is only one web.**

Comment: Which device as a 3.0 pixel ratio!? I need to get one!

Comment: HTC Butterfly;
Nexus 5;
Samsung Galaxy S4;
Sony Xperia Z :-)

Comment: ... also the HTC One and I think the Xiaomi Mi2 - for those who've seen Stephanie Rieger's most excellent talk/slideshare on [designing for diversity](http://www.slideshare.net/yiibu/designing-for-diversity-how-to-stop-worrying-and-embrace-the-android-revolution)